# Micro seconds length sine pulses/waves

Tags: arduino

Wonder about the speed of an **Arduino UNO R3**. Want to send out bursts of sine waves via an **AD9850** connected to my **Arduino UNO R3**.

Question: If using the Arduino to set the frequency of the **AD9850**; will the Arduino be fast enough to generate bursts/short periods of sine waves via the **AD9850**.

Like this, for example:

```
void sendFunction(double frequency, double sendTime, double guardTime) {
    for (int n=0; n<4; n++ )//(buttonstate4 == HIGH)
    {
        DDS.setfreq(frequency, 0);      // the signal
        delay(sendTime);
        DDS.setfreq(0, 0);              // the guard; time of silence, i.e., no frequency
        delay(guardTime);
        DDS.setfreq(frequency, 0);
        delay(sendTime);
        DDS.setfreq(0, 0);
        delay(guardTime);
    }
}
```

// AVR08

Comment: what is "fast enough"? this cannot be answered without knowing more on the library you're using. the best way to check this is to hook it up to an oscilloscope

Comment: The length of sendTime and guardTime should be in microseconds, e.g., 4 microseconds for sendTime and 6 microseconds for guardTime.
Will the setup of it all be able to run at such fast pace?

Comment: I mean; will the setup of things actually be able to produce such an outgoing sinewave in such short "pulses"?

Comment: (Why I'm asking this is because I can program it; but I can not control/verify if it is actually working at thoose speeds - i.e., I can not see the pulses of waves at my oscilloscope because of the speed.)

Comment: delay() does not take a double ( or float ) argument. You could read a bit about `delayMicroseconds()` and learn how you come beyond those limits, if necessary. The speed of an Uno is 62.5 nanoseconds per clock cycle  (16MHz)

Comment: It's possible, You should use inline assembler for that, though.  Put your function in a separate  .cpp file to unlock all of gcc's power.

Comment: Many thanks, datafiddler and Michaël Roy!!